# Wordpress 301 redirect with questionmark ? from one domain to new domain with different url structure

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I tried a lot, looked in the other posts but didn't get it to work..

1. I want to redirect  olddomain.com/?portfolio=this-is-the-title-of-the-post to newdomain.com/portfolio/newtitle1/
2. I want to redirect olddomain.com//?portfolio=10689 to newdomain.com/portfolio/newtitle2/
3. I want to check if mu redirect olddomain.com to newdomain.com is set correct

**UPDATE:** After your first answers I updated it to this but still not working:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^portfolio=this-is-the-title-of-the-post$
RewriteRule ^ http://newsite.com/portfolio/newtitle1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^portfolio=10689$
RewriteRule ^ http://newsite.com/portfolio/newtitle2/? [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# BEGIN 301 Redirects
Redirect 301 /index.php http://newsite.com
Redirect 301 /cart/ http://shop.newsite.com/cart/
Redirect 301 /my-account/ http://shop.newsite.com/my-account/
Redirect 301 /shop/ http://shop.newsite.com/
Redirect 301 /portfolio-one-column-standard-style/ http://newsite.com/portfolio/
Redirect 301 /home/blog/ http://newsite.com/blog/
Redirect 301 /about/ http://newsite.com/about/
# END 301 Redirects
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these 2 rules at top of your .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} portfolio=this-is-the-title-of-the-post
RewriteRule ^ http://newsite.com/portfolio/newtitle1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} portfolio=10689
RewriteRule ^ http://newsite.com/portfolio/newtitle2/? [R=301,L]

# BEGIN 301 Redirects
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ http://newsite.com/ [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^cart/ http://shop.newsite.com/cart/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^my-account/ http://shop.newsite.com/my-account/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/ http://shop.newsite.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^portfolio-one-column-standard-style/ http://newsite.com/portfolio/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^home/blog/ http://newsite.com/blog/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^about/ http://newsite.com/about/ [R=301,L]
# END 301 Redirects

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
Make sure to clear your browser cache before you test.
```

Comment: nope... doesnt seem the work, also not when I add 'RewriteEngine On' above it. It still redirects  olddomain.com/?portfolio=item1-test to newdomain.com/?portfolio=item1-test instead of to newdomain.com/portfolio/item1/

Comment: clearded cache, put those exact four lines on the top of the .htaccess file with after that the # BEGIN WordPress and # BEGIN 301 Redirects... no success

Comment: updated the .htaccess to your specs, cleared history + cache of firefox, but now none of the old urls redirect...

Comment: If even `http://oldside.com/cart` isnt redirecting then you don't have `mod_rewrite` enabled in Apache config.

Comment: I uploaded the file in the root / ... which did work, but it needed to be in the /public_html folder. Solution: no htaccess file in the root /, only the new one in the public_html folder. Problem solved! Thanks

Comment: Yes `public_html` is indeed the website's root.

Comment: btw.. I now see that everything redirects except the main domain. so the olddomain.com isnt redirecting to newdomain.com

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `RewriteEngine On` before below rules:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^portfolio=this-is-the-title-of-the-post$
RewriteRule ^ http://newsite.com/portfolio/newtitle1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^portfolio=10689$
RewriteRule ^ http://newsite.com/portfolio/newtitle2/? [R=301,L]
```